# How to host a flask web app on my own pc?

Tags: python, web, flask, host

Im developing an app using flask framework in python, i wanted to host it on my pc for a few people to be able to visit it, similar to wamps put online feature but for flask instead, i dont want to deploy it to the cloud just yet. how can i do it.

Comment: Do you have a static ip?

Comment: yes i have a static ip setup already

Comment: Then you are good to go. All you need is a WSGI server and a proxy server like nginx. BTW, this question is off-topic for stackoverflow, so I voted to close. There are other server related SE sites but you should first google it.

Comment: i read it, can uwsgi run on windows, or is it only for linux

Answer (score 1):

Enable port forwarding on your router, start flask on the 0.0.0.0 address of your computer, set the forwarded port to be the one started on your laptop. This will now allow your LAN and calls to your ISP provided address to be directed to your laptop.

To clarify, LAN can do it without port forwarding in my experience.